# Dashing Framework not connecting to database

Tags: ruby, sql-server, widget, jobs, dashing

I am trying to connect a dashing number widget to an sql query that is run in sqlserver. This is my job script:

```
require 'mysql2'

current_count = 0
final count = 0

SCHEDULER.every '5m', :first_in => 0 do |job|

final_count = current_count

  # Mysql connection
  db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "xxx.xxx.xx.xx", :username => "xxxxxxx", :password => "xxxxxxxxxx", :port => 3306, :database => "xxxxxxxxxx") 

  # Mysql query
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM dbo.Idea"

  # Execute the query
  results = db.query(sql)

  if(results)
    current_count = results['total']

    send_event('final_count', {value: current_count})

  end

end
```

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong but I am new to ruby and dashing and am unsure where to go from here. Is there a good way to debug code in ruby? Specifically this job?
Thanks

---

Hey guys, so I changed my development environment and then got the gem debugger working, so I have rewritten the code as follows. When the code runs it pulls the value from the database in the following form `{"total"=>93}`, however the value is still not showing up in the widgets. I have a number widget and a meter widget, both should display `93` for testing purposes. I did insert a dummy value to make sure the linking was working correctly and it is. How can I format the result? I tried JSON parse however it crashed the program.

```
require 'debugger'

require 'tiny_tds'


SCHEDULER.every '300s', :first_in => 0 do |job|

debugger

client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'xxxxxxx', :password => 'xxxxxxxxxx', :host => 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx')
 rs = client.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM xxxxxxxxxx.dbo.Idea")
 rs.each do |row| 

 send_event('final_count', {value: row['value'] })
 end
 client.close

end
```

Comment: You seem to be throwing the value of the sql query. After you query the database, you rewrite the variable holding the information. Is this intentional?

Comment: No it's not, I will fix that first.

Comment: you're missing the closing parens in #new call to the mysql client

Comment: Are you getting any error output when running this?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot - Thank you for pointing that out. It was a copy paste error, the original file has the paren.

Comment: @JustinWood - I am not getting any output. I tried to drop a debugger line in and all it accomplished was crashing the program.

Comment: Is there a good way to test and see if the job is connecting to the database in the first place?

Comment: You could look into using something like the `pry` gem. For a very simple 'debug' you could litter your code with `puts` to output data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Justin Wood, I will look into them and see if I can figure it out. I'll update after.

Comment: I updated my code after Sam and your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so since my query results were aliased you have to use the alias name instead of value. The following change allows for the meter widget to display the data. Thank you to everyone’s help.

```
 send_event('finalCount', {value: row['total'] })
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments that you're looking for a good way to debug your code. Justin Wood gives some good ideas by suggesting `pry` and `puts`, and those would be a good start.

Something else to try would be to catch exceptions. For example:

```
SCHEDULER.every '5m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
   begin
        db = Mysql2::Client.new(...)
        # The rest of your code
   rescue => e
        puts "Exception occurred: #{e}"
   end
end
```

This will print out any exceptions that occur. The exceptions might give you a clearer idea of exactly what's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Great that you found it out! 
But as you are doing a `Select Count(*) from xxxxx` and because of that, its results has just one row, you could get only the first result. And you can also put your query statement in another place to make things cleaner.

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'xxxxxxx', :password => 'xxxxxxxxxx', :host => 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx')
count_query= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM xxxxxxxxxx.dbo.Idea"
count = client.execute(count_query).first

send_event('final_count', {value: count['total'] })

client.close
```

Comment: Very true, however this was simply a rudimentary attempt at bringing in data stored in a DB to Dashing. Also, the select count statement is giving me the number of rows in the DB table, so a result of one row is fine.